# I want to create a Scissor Paper Rock program in PYTHON. It worked BUT, It keeps on printing "none" at the end

Tags: python, printing, nonetype

I can't find the "NONE" which keeps printing after DISPLAYING the message

```
whats your move on "scissor" "paper" and "rock" ?!
 rock
computer-paper
sorry man you lost
None



message={
        "loose":"sorry man you lost",
        "win":"YOU WIN ",
        "tie":"it's a tie"
    }
    
    def game(user,comp):
        if user==comp:
            print(message.get("tie"))
        elif user=="scissor" and comp=="paper":
            print(message.get("win"))
        elif user=="paper" and comp=="rock":
            print(message.get("win"))
        elif user=="rock" and comp=="scissor":
            print(message.get("win"))
        else:
            print(message.get("loose"))
    
    
    
    user=input('''what's your move on "scissor" "paper" and "rock" ?!\n ''')
    
    import random
    comp=random.randint(1,3)
    if comp==1:
        comp="scissor"
    elif comp==2:
        comp="paper"
    elif comp==3:
        comp="rock"
    
    print("computer-",comp)
    
    x=(game(user,comp))
    print(x)
```

Comment: Did you consider that `x` might be `None`?

Comment: What does `game` return that you think should be getting printed?

Comment: hey, thank you very much. I have another similar question I want to define the computer move as a function but every time I do that, the output is so random like scissor scissor you loose and next time(without making any changes) scissor rock it's a tie and next time(without making any changes) scissor scissor you win –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `game()` function prints things, but it doesn't *return* anything.

So when you print the return value of `game()`, you print None.

Comment: hey, thank you very much. I have another similar question
I want to define the computer move as a function but every time I do that, the output is so random like 
scissor 
scissor 
you loose 

and next time(without making any changes)
scissor
rock
it's a tie

and next time(without making any changes)

scissor 
scissor
you win